# Check if array key exists in a multidimentional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array that's generated using mysql like this:

```
$conn = connect();
$stmt = $conn->prepare("select id, type, status from arraytest");
$stmt->execute();
$myArray = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

When I do `print_r($myArray)`, I get this:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 3 [0] => 3 [type] => 0 [1] => 0 [status] => 0 [2] => 0 ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 6 [0] => 6 [type] => 0 [1] => 0 [status] => 1 [2] => 1 ) )
```

I can also access the array this way:

```
echo $myArray[0][0]. ' ' . $myArray[0][1]. ' ' . $myArray[0][2];
echo '<br>';
echo $myArray[1][0]. ' ' . $myArray[1][1]. ' ' . $myArray[1][2];
```

The table data is simple:

```
"id"    "type"  "status"
"3"    "0"      "0"
"6"    "0"      "1"
```

I need to run the array against a while loop and check if `id` from the array matches the `$i`. But how is this done with an array like this? I cant figure out? Can you please help?

```
while ($i <= 10) {
    echo $i;
    echo ((array_key_exists($i,$myArray)) ? ' OK <br>' : ' Fail <br>'); // I need to check if $i == id from the array. 
    $i++;
    echo '<br>';
}
```

**Expected Output**

```
1 Fail
2 Fail
3 OK
4 Fail
5 Fail
6 OK
//and so on
```

Comment: So your expected output is 1 fail, 2 fail, 3 ok, 4 fail, 5 fail, 6 ok, 7 fail, etc.. with the data table from the question?

Comment: You're absolutely correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
while ($i <= 10) {
    echo $i;
    echo ($i==$myArray[$i]['id']) ? ' OK <br>' : ' Fail <br>';
    $i++;
    echo '<br>';
}
```

**Edit**

After the edit to your Question, this is a different story. Try this:

```
while ($i <= 10) {
    echo $i;
    $msg=' Fail <br>';
    foreach ($myArray as $v)
        if ($i==$v['id']) $msg=' OK <br>';
    echo $msg;
    $i++;
    echo '<br>';
}
```

Comment: Tried the same thing yesterday. Does not work. Returns fail for all + `Notice: Undefined offset: 2` for all but 0 and 1

Comment: ofcourse - if you only havce 2 rows. Ah, I now see your OQ edit ... updating my answer.

Comment: Hehe new version will echo 'Fail' for every index, for every record that doesn't match :-)

Comment: 1 Fail Fail, 2 Fail Fail, 3 OK Fail, 4 Fail Fail, etc

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the following code to get that. This is the generic code

```
<?php

/**
 * Get list of all keys of a multidimentional array
 *
 * @param array $array Multidimensional array to extract keys from
 * @return array
 */
function array_keys_multi(array $array)
{
    $keys = array();

    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        $keys[] = $key;

        if (is_array($array[$key])) {
            $keys = array_merge($keys, array_keys_multi($array[$key]));
        }
    }

    return $keys;
}
```

Comment: Cant `id` in the array be directly accessed?

Answer (score 0):

This involves fairly minimal changes to your code:

```
while ($i <= 10) {
    echo $i;
    $matched = array_filter($myArray, function($record) use ($i) {
        return $record['id'] === $i;
    });
    echo !empty($matched) ? ' OK <br>' : ' Fail <br>';
    $i++;
    echo '<br>';
}
```

In each loop, `$matched` is set to the array of records where the id is equal to `$i`.  This will be non-empty if there is a match, otherwise empty.

Of course you could also use a normal `foreach` loop to determine if there is a matching id.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php